# Add bookmarklet to mobile safari

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

Is there some easy method for installing bookmarklets on an iPad/iOS device that does't involve syncing my bookmarks with a computer somewhere?

Examples showing the sync with computer installation.

- http://helpdesk.lastpass.com/bookmarklets/#Installing+Bookmarklets+on+the+iPad
- https://support.pinterest.com/entries/21033321-how-do-i-install-the-pin-it-bookmarklet-on-an-ipad-iphone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Copy/Paste Method

1. On your device, copy the bookmarklet code.

   - If you don't have the bookmarklet code in plain text (just a link), the easiest thing to do is open the page with the link on a Mac or PC, copy the javascript contents of the bookmarklet and email them to yourself, then copy that on your device.
2. Create a new bookmark for any site (doesn't matter which one).
3. Open the bookmarks menu, tap **Edit** and select the bookmark you just created.
4. Paste the bookmarklet code in place of the URL, then change the name to whatever you want.

That should give you a working bookmarklet without having to mess around with syncing.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something obvious, but step 1 is the part that I am not sure how to accomplish.  How are you actually copying the bookmarklet code?

Comment: Oh, I thought this was a bookmarklet you had the text code to. I take it that there's a bookmarklet link rather than text code. In that case, I suggest opening the page with the bookmarklet link on a Mac or PC, copying the text there (which unfortunately you can't do with iOS AFAICT), and emailing it to yourself. I'll add this to the answer.

Comment: @robmathers i text myself bookmarklets so they are accessible for copy/pasting in ios.